# Why has my Cygwin prompt stopped being bold? (or rather started being "dim"...!)

Tags: command-line, cygwin, prompt

This is not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294857/my-zsh-prompt-is-not-bold).

In my case I have a simple Cygwin installation. Up to now the prompt has been in a bold green colour (my name) followed by a bold yellow colour (location).  The $ is bold on the next line.

I wanted to change the location of my Home directory so I changed cygwin.bat to this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set HOME=D:\My Documents\Software projects\Cygwin\Mike
D:
chdir D:\apps\cygwin64\bin
bash --login -i
```

Line 2 and 3 here have been added by me.

This works great: I've also added a shortcut to this .bat file to

```
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

so that I can start a terminal in any location from the Explorer context menu... and "cd ~" takes me to the above "HOME" location.

But my name (green) and the location (yellow) are now unbolded. Does anyone know what this means?

***later***
thanks to David Postill, following his answers:
in the (real) '~' directory:

```
$ grep -Irn 'PS1' --include="*profile*" 2> /dev/null
$ grep -Irn 'PS1' --include="*bash*" 2> /dev/null
```

Both of these returned nothing at all... from this I concluded that the default prompt was coming from somewhere else... and also surmised that in the new "remote" HOME directory I could then add a PS1 value to my .bashrc.

```
PS1="\[\033[1;32m\]\u@\h:\[\033[1;33m\]\w\n\[\033[0;37m\]\$ "
```

and I got a BOLD prompt.  But I then realised that the problem was not that the prompt here had been "non-bold", it was that it had been "dim" (see [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/)).

Great, I thought, do this:

```
PS1="\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h:\[\033[0;33m\]\w\n\[\033[0;37m\]\$ "
```

... because 0 before the semicolon is meant to be "normal" (2 is meant to be "dim")... But the prompt then came out not normal... but dim again. Grrrrrr.  I give up (temporarily!).

Answer (score 1):

#### my name (green) and the location (yellow) are now unbolded.

Your prompt environment variable `PS1` is normally used to set things like name and location in your bash prompt.

This variable is normally set in `~/.bashrc` which is located in your `cygwin` home directory.

You have changed `HOME` to a new location where there is no `.bashrc` file (or presumably other personal configuration files (for example `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, `.history`, etc)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.)](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)
- [Bash prompt basics](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-prompt-basics)

Comment: Thanks... in fact in that new location there *are* the same .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile files.  But, spurred on by your suggestion, I went to see if I could spot an uncommented line configuring the prompt ... I couldn't.  Even if your idea had been 100% correct (you're probably on the right lines), you don't offer an explanation of why the non-bolding occurs, or what it means...

Comment: @mikerodent The non bolding can occur if your prompt is set incorrectly and/or your terminal emulator does not have bold enabled. See [How to make the terminal display user@machine in bold letters?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/31695)